# Output Content-Type from HEAD request

Tags: go

I am making a simple HEAD request, and I'm looking to see if the returned Content-Type contains a  zip file.

I know you can do this:

```
  res, err := http.Head(url)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
    return false
  }
  contentlength:=res.ContentLength
  fmt.Printf("ContentLength:%v\n", contentlength)
```

But what about `Content-Type` is there any way to access it? I thought about two ideas:

```
  contentType:=res.ContentType
```

But that doesn't exist:

> res.ContentType undefined (type *http.Response has no field or method ContentType)

And what about just trying to parse the whole contents of 'res' so I can just look for the substring 'zip':

```
  bs := string(res)
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", bs)
```

> cannot convert res (type *http.Response) to type string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the contents of header

```golang
contentType := res.Header.Get("Content-Type")
```

See [Header.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get) and [CanonicalHeaderKey](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CanonicalHeaderKey)

Comment: Awesome thanks! It's always so easy when you see how it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the additional linked resources; helpful!